# Expression to catch Single Quote & Special Characters using ValidationExpression in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am working on the asp.net webpage and in the FileUpload control, I am using the `ValidationExpression` to detect if the selected file has the needed image extension or not. So far it is working fine but I am struggling to detect **Single Quote** or **Special characters** in the file name selected by the user with-in the same expression. The idea is to refrain user to use the special characters.

The current code is

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
   runat="server" ID="ImageUpload_TypeValidation" 
   ControlToValidate="txt_CategoryPicture" Display="Dynamic" 
   ErrorMessage="Only files with extension JPG/JPEG/GIF/PNG/TIF/BMP are allowed."
   SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="AddNewCategory"
   ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.jpg|.JPG|.png|.PNG|.jpeg|.JPEG|.gif|.GIF|.tif|.TIF|.bmp|.BMP)$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Appreciate.

Comment: Kindly provide the name you're trying to pass right now

Comment: @Tans, I am looking at characters like `',":;{}[])(&^%$#@!~` `=+></?\|/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to generate the unique file name for every file upload using Microsoft's inbuilt function of `GUID.NewGUID()` and converting the image files to `.png` type. This eliminates any special characters that I didn't want user to have as a filename. Another benefit is that the system will always get the unique file name.

`strUploadedFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() & ".png"`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check and verify this regex.

`^.*[\w\s].*[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]*[\w\s].*(.jpg|.JPG|.png|.PNG|.jpeg|.JPEG|.gif|.GIF|.tif|.TIF|.bmp|.BMP)$`

Comment: Thanks for the regex. Unfortunately the regex is not detecting any of the special characters mentioned above from the file chosen. The file that I have is `Tul'ip}.png`

Comment: Can you try one thing more as you want each and every character so it is possible that only (.*)  will work. This basically represents everything.

Comment: I tried with this, but bad luck, the new code is `^(.*)(.jpg|.JPG|.png|.PNG|.jpeg|.JPEG|.gif|.GIF|.tif|.TIF|.bmp|.BMP)$`